# Proxy only POST requests (or any other HTTP method) through Webpack Dev Server?

Tags: http-proxy, webpack-dev-server

Is there any way to only allow POST requests to be proxied using Webpack Dev Server?  My app uses /login for GET requests and unfortunately it is being proxied to my other host regardless of HTTP method.

```
    // Serve the Relay app
    const compiler = webpack(config);
    appServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
        contentBase: '/public/',
        proxy: {
            '/login': `http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}`, // only for POST?
        },
        publicPath: '/js/',
        stats: {
            colors: true,
            chunks: false,
        },
        historyApiFallback: true
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use bypass parameter.

```
// Serve the Relay app
const compiler = webpack(config);
appServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
    contentBase: '/public/',
    proxy: {
        '/login': {
            target: `http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}`, // only for POST?
            bypass: function(req, res, proxyOptions) {
                if(req.method != 'POST') return false;
            }
        }
    },
    publicPath: '/js/',
    stats: {
        colors: true,
        chunks: false,
    },
    historyApiFallback: true
});
```

[documentation Webpack 1](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#bypass-the-proxy)

[documentation Webpack 2](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy)

Comment: The bypass signature is `(req, res)` not `(res, req)`. `bypass: req => req.method !== 'POST' ? false : undefined` is sufficient.

Comment: @greenimpala you are right, thanks for pointing this out. I will stick with more verbose (IMHO easier for beginners) version.